# Mudar a forma do output de aggregation, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Eu tenho uma collection `client` com vários `records` no seguinte formato:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    username: 'username',
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    price: 9.99,
    preference: 'VIP'
}
```

Preciso utilizar um `aggregate` para somar os `price` de acordo com o `preference`.

Para isso utilizei: `db.client.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "$preference", value: { $sum: "$price" }   } } ])`

Resultando em:

```
[
  { _id: 'VIP', value: 83.94999999999999 },
  { _id: 'VIP+', value: 619.99 },
  { _id: 'Normal', value: 34.93 }
]
```

Mas a forma com que ele deve sair é:

```
{
  results: [
    { _id: 'VIP', value: 83.94999999999999 },
    { _id: 'VIP+', value: 619.99 },
    { _id: 'Normal', value: 34.93 },
  ],
  ok: 1
}
```

Não estou conseguindo encontrar uma maneira de alterar a forma do `output`.

Obs: precisa ser resolvido 100% com MongoDB Aggregations

Comment: Poderia fazer a mudança na camada de lógica de negócio.

Comment: Hmm, poderia explicar melhor?
Estou começando a estudar MongoDB faz pouco tempo, esse é um exercício que estou realizando e precisa ser resolvido 100% com MongoDB aggregation, e o que seria a camada de lógica de negócio?

Comment: Poderia colocar essas informações na pergunta? Como tem que ser resolvido 100% com mongodb, você não possui a camada de negócios.

Comment: Veja se [isto](https://mongoplayground.net/p/On16UebtvQv) atende sua necessidade, por favor.

Comment: @Rfroes87 muito obrigado, atende perfeitamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método que você adotou está correto, porém para formatar conforme desejado é necessário implementar mais 2 etapas do *pipeline* de agregação ([Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)), particularmente o [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) (independente da primeira utilização do mesmo) e [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

No final, o comando de agregação completo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
db.client.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$preference",
      "value": {
        $sum: "$price"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "results": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "results": 1,
      "ok": {
        $toInt: "1"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

## Etapas (Pipeline Stages)

### **1.** `{ $group: { _id: "$preference", value: { $sum: "$price" } } }`

Agrupa documentos pelo valor da propriedade `preference` e aplica a operação de soma cumulativa baseada no atributo `price` para todos os documentos de cada grupo distinto.

### **2.** `{ $group: { _id: null, results: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }`

Agrupa todos os documentos incluindo a propriedade `_id` com valor `null` no documento raiz único resultante e anexando todos os documentos originais ([`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.ROOT) referindo-se a cada um deles) processados em um *Array* chamado `results`.

### **3.** `{ $project: { _id: 0, "results": 1, "ok": { $toInt: "1" } } }`

Determina quais propriedades serão exibidas — somente uma pode ser suprimida (isto é, valor *booleano* `0` ou *`false`*) por vez com exceção de `_id` ou utilização do operador [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) com [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.REMOVE) —, preservando então `results` e adicionando `ok` com valor inteiro `1`.

## OUTPUT

### Entrada (*collection* `client`)

```
[
  {
    _id: "a",
    username: "username",
    email: "email",
    password: "password",
    price: 9.99,
    preference: "VIP"
  },
  {
    _id: "b",
    username: "username",
    email: "email",
    password: "password",
    price: 10.99,
    preference: "VIP"
  },
  {
    _id: "c",
    username: "username",
    email: "email",
    password: "password",
    price: 7.99,
    preference: "VIP+"
  }
]
```

### Saída

```
[
  {
    "ok": 1,
    "results": [
      {
        "_id": "VIP",
        "value": 20.98
      },
      {
        "_id": "VIP+",
        "value": 7.99
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Reproduzido em [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PVh-hz44ljh).